# When to use web sockets versus HTTP when using Tcl as a local server in a desktop application?

Tags: websocket, tcl

I'm attempting to build a desktop application using Tcl with SQLite and a web browser as the UI (with some Tk). The Tcl code can now handle communication with the browser through regular HTTP fetch requests and web sockets, but I'm trying to understand which should be used and when, and have a few questions please.

Now that I'm finally connecting the UI with the Tcl, I'm not sure what is gained through the use of a web socket. I understand that it provides that ability to initiate events in the browser from Tcl; and I have a use for that. However, **1) for what might be termed "regular" requests initiated by a user action in the UI, should HTTP or a web socket be used, or should they be reserved only for initiating communication from server to client?**

The headers sent by Tcl to the browser request that the connection be kept alive; but, after two minutes of inactivity, the browser closes the connection. So, when I first read about web sockets, I thought they were going to offer some form of increased efficiency in providing a continuous open connection due to Tcl not having to keep opening and closing connections with nearly every new request. But the incoming web socket requests have to be decoded in Tcl before they can be parsed and executed, and some form of ID needs to be used in order for the browser to know which reponse received from Tcl over the socket correlates to which original request. I have a way of doing this that seems to be working well, and the requests are always a rather small amount of data such that decoding is minor. But **2) Is the trade off between not having to open a new connection for nearly every request against having to decode incoming requests and the browser reading data frames on the other end expected to result in increased efficiency or better user experience?**

In the case of starting the program, there could be the need for executing maybe 20 to 50 small SQL queries, especially if the user chooses to restore a saved previous session. **3) Is using a single web socket preferrable to using multiple HTTP fetch requests, after which the many sockets will be closed? If a single socket is used, will there be some sort of bottle-neck in attempting to send multiple concurrent responses over the single socket?**

The database is something of a study library including document scans and audio lectures. When using fetch to request an image, the promise handlers are coded on that request to do something with the image when received; but, when using a socket, there has to be something in front of that image to tell the JS code to which request it is in response and what function to invoke to process it. Thus, a blob has to be sliced (which appears to make a [copy of the entire blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73002253/is-it-possible-to-read-a-portion-of-a-blob-without-copying-it-through-blob-splic) even to read only the first few bytes). I have code that retrieves the scans through a web socket and I cannot visibly see any difference between it and an HTTP fetch and it varies based upon what is in the SQLite memory cache anyway (at least I think that is the case) such that it isn't that easy to test. **4) Is retrieving images a proper use of a web socket?** Also, I was thinking that I could use a separate socket for the audio such that a user could listen to a lecture while examining the documents and/or employing the other tools. **5) Is playing audio a proper use of a web socket?**

I apologize for what may be peurile questions but I don't have enough experience or background to really determine if there is anything gained through using web sockets for most requests. Most likely, a user of this application will run a few search queries after which nearly every request will be spaced by more than two minutes as they read a document; and they might listen to a lecture while perusing other material or type notes. It seems possible to use either method.

Thank you for considering my question.